# Visualforce Page - Vertical

Tags: visualforce

Is there a way to create a vertical table using visualforce?  Something like this the followng.  But instead of hardcoding the data, I want to use a list for the values.  Thanks!!!

```
  <table>
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>number</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>James Bond</td>
    <td>007</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>555</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at [`apex:datatable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) or [`apex:repeat`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm)?

Comment: Also curious why you are building anything in VisualForce at this point?

Comment: @David I have used datatable and repeat but that presents the data as as rows.. I want to present the data so each record is vertical.  Adrain.  I have a 14 year old instance with a lot of functionality.  I have converted some users to lighting but converting this to lighting would mean a very large lift.  Hope that helps solve your curiousity. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify what you mean by vertical vs horizontal with screenshots of what you want to see.  The HTML you've include presents the data in a row format, just like what datatable does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of your example, [`apex:repeat`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm) is a good option. If your data is sObjects, I like to use `$ObjectType.<object-name>.fields.<field-name>.Label` to get the field labels. I used Contacts in my example since you didn't provide what type of object you're working with, but adapt this to your own page.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.Label}</th>
            <th>{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Number.Label}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <apex:repeat var="person" value="{!contacts}">
            <tr>
                <td>{!person.Name}</td>
                <td>{!person.Number}</td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As others have suggested in comments, `apex:datatable` is also a fine option with similar results, just different syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this sample code to create table in Visualforce page:-

```xml
<apex:page standardController="Account">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
      You are viewing the {!account.name} account.
   </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.Contacts}" var="contact">
         <apex:column value="{!contact.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Also refer this [link](https://sfdctree.wordpress.com/2018/08/23/how-to-display-data-in-table-format-in-visualforce-with-pagination/)

Comment: I have added a picture of what I mean by Vertical Table.  thanks!!